# In case of fresh install (no existing OS) how to diagnose which Windows 11 hardware requirement does not meet?

Tags: windows, setup, windows-11

**Context**

Installing Windows 11 to a computer, with one single empty drive (no existing OS) and the installer gives the "This PC does not meet the minimum requirements..."

I know this point it is possible to press `shift + f10`, and get a console prompt.

**Question**

Is there any log file or diagnostics information to look for about what "does not meet"?

Comment: You apparently have the correct specifications. Contact the manufacturer and ask why the new computer will not run Windows 11.  My new computer is running Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: At the point where you are arguing with the installer you might as well just [download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/eb-gb/software-download/windows10) and then run the [windows 11 health check app](https://aka.ms/GetPCHealthCheckApp)

Comment: You should also be specific about your system. What processor does it have? Windows 11 requires at least an 8th Generation Intel processor or equivalent AMD, "2 cores 2.8GHz" does not tell us if the system you bought meets that requirement.

Comment: The [WhyNotWin11 tool](https://www.whynotwin11.com/) may give better information about the Windows 11 compatibility of your computer.

Comment: See the edited question. Maybe the original phrasing was a bit chatty, but the intention was exactly the same. I hope when facing an error message, the intended practice to look for more detailed diagnostic error information is a good idea, so asking how to do it is a legit and useful question.  Because of the scenario (no existing previous OS) this is definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: It would be good to say exactly where and at what stage you get this message. Screenshot or photos may even help.the problem is that if you are still in the installer then the environment is even more basic than a Linux Live USB environment and there may be no logs to speak of. I mention using Windows 10 because it is trivial to get a hold of and works on almost all hardware and on top of that the upgrade setup logs are far easier to get to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/log-files. There are also applications dedicated to diagnosing your system.

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't ask only where the setup might tell you something, just that if you actually want to resolve the problem there are other far more reliable and likely methods to do so.

Comment: @mokubai, in the prev version of the OP which was closed, there was specified where I got the error message.  I would not say it is a preferred way Install Win 10 to the machine, then upgrading to Win 11 is **just for the sake** to know what was the error in an **other** installation process, in an **other** installation scenario in an **other** installation state. The the intent of the OP is not how to diag.a PC for Win 11 compatibility, neither how to workaround the installation failure. I focus on, how to get the diag. info of a particular execution os a program in a particular state.